# How does pseudoinverse quadric fitting in Meshlab compute the principal curvatures?

Tags: surface, meshlab

I tried finding any reference for Pseudoinverse Quadric Fitting but didn't find any. I am trying to obtain curvature of a surface with edges (not closed). This method seems to assign a certain negative value of curvature at the edge. I am not sure why. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the algorithm that computes curvature in MeshLab under the name *Pseudoinverse Quadric Fitting*:

- for each point it chooses a set of nearest vertexes within a given radius,
- computes a projection plane by averaging its normals and
- fits a quadric of these points wrt this plane.

Curvature directions and values are the ones of this fitted quadric.
To fit the quad the code uses a SVD decomposition hence the pseudoinverse name.
Code is here
https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib/blob/devel/vcg/complex/algorithms/update/curvature_fitting.h